# Laravel File Upload Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload a file in Laravel but it displays an error like...

> FileException in UploadedFile.php line 251: The file "April.xlsx" was
>   not uploaded due to an unknown error.

I already use `'files'=>true` in my form tag and in my controller code I have...

```
<?php

$mandatoryDocument = $input['mandatoryDocument'];
if ($mandatoryDocument != null) {
    $mandatoryFile = time() . '-' . $mandatoryDocument->getClientOriginalName();
    $mandatoryDocument->move(public_path() . '/files/mandatory_documents/', $mandatoryFile);
    $achievement->file_path = $mandatoryFile;
}
```

When I `dd($input['mandatoryDocument'])` in the controller I get the error...

> UploadedFile {#27 ▼   -test: false   -originalName: "April.xlsx"
>   -mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
>   -size: 12297   -error: 0 }

The file successfully moved to `/public/files/mandatory_documents`
but with that error. Where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: A lot of questions here to add : what"s your post max size? What's your default upload dir? What object are you using in your controller to wrap your file upload? What is your view code? Please add all this to your original question, not accurate enough at this stage. :)

Comment: Also make sure the directory you are uploading has read/writing permissions. It's a common mistake :)

Comment: Gotta be permissions - the file gets uploaded successfully as we can see from the `dd` output - it's `move` that fails, so permissions in the `public/files/mandatory_documents/` path is the culprit.